# Moshi : Generic Json converter for Room entity

Tags: android, json, gson, moshi

I am trying to create a generic JSON parser String to Object with Moshi but I am not sure if I am doing it right as I am stuck in a scenario which needs to deal with List.

The idea of this interface is it can be implemented either with a Gson or Moshi parser

```
interface JsonParser {

    fun <T> fromJson(jsonString: String, type: Class<T>): T?

    fun <T> toJson(obj: T, type: Class<T>): String?

}
```

Sample Moshi parser

```
class MoshiParser(private val moshi: Moshi) : JsonParser {

    override fun <T> fromJson(jsonString: String, type: Class<T>): T? {
        return moshi.adapter(type).fromJson(jsonString)
    }

    override fun <T> toJson(obj: T, type: Class<T>): String? {
        return moshi.adapter(type).toJson(obj)
    }

}
```

Sample converter class

```
    @ProvidedTypeConverter
    class JsonConverter(private val jsonParser: JsonParser) {
    
        @TypeConverter
        fun fromMetricsJson(jsonString: String): MetricsDomain {
            return jsonParser.fromJson(jsonString, MetricsDomain::class.java)
                ?: MetricsDomain() // Empty
        }
    
        @TypeConverter
        fun toMetricsJson(obj: MetricsDomain): String {
            return jsonParser.toJson(obj, MetricsDomain::class.java)
                ?: DEFAULT_VALUE_STRING // Empty
        }

    }
```

But how can I work with something like List?

```
@TypeConverter
    fun fromHistoricalValuesJson(jsonString: String): List<List<Double>> {
        return jsonParser.fromJson(jsonString, // How to do this in Moshi)
            ?: emptyList()
    }
```

In Gson I think we can do it like `object : TypeToken<ArrayList<List<Double>>>(){}.type`, in Moshi we can use reified extension according to docs but I cannot do that in this case.

```
// We can just use a reified extension!
val adapter = moshi.adapter<List<Card>>()
```

Sample data class

```
@Parcelize
data class MetricsDomain(
    val riskMetricsDomain: RiskMetricsDomain = RiskMetricsDomain(),
    val roiByYearDomain: RoiByYearDomain = RoiByYearDomain(),
    val roiDataDomain: RoiDataDomain = RoiDataDomain(),
    val supplyDomain: SupplyDomain = SupplyDomain()
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: You're looking for Moshi's Types utilities: `Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, Double.class))`

Comment: @EricCochran yes, does it use reflection?

Comment: Types are in the Java reflect package, but making them is cheap (same as Gson making Type instances).

Comment: @EricCochran How is the performance of doing it as Bitwise DEVS answer below VS Richard Ory's answer also below? Is there a preference on any of these ways of doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to do it using generic types thanks to @Eric comment.

```
class MoshiParser(private val moshi: Moshi) : JsonParser {

    override fun <T> fromJson(jsonString: String, type: Type): T? {
        return moshi.adapter<T>(type).fromJson(jsonString)
    }

    override fun <T> toJson(obj: T, type: Type): String? {
        return moshi.adapter<T>(type).toJson(obj)
    }

}
```

In your `@ProvidedTypeConverter` annotated class

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromListDoubleValuesJson(jsonString: String): List<List<Double>> {
        return jsonParser.fromJson(
            jsonString,
            Types.newParameterizedType(
                List::class.java,
                Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, Double::class.javaObjectType)
            )
        )
            ?: emptyList()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toListDoubleValuesJson(obj: List<List<Double>>): String {
        return jsonParser.toJson(
            obj,
            Types.newParameterizedType(
                List::class.java,
                Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, Double::class.javaObjectType)
            )
        )
            ?: DEFAULT_VALUE_STRING
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put these 2 functions in a kotlin file :

```
val moshi: Moshi = Moshi
    .Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()    

inline fun <reified T> convertJsonToObject(json: String): T = 
    moshi.adapter(T::class.java).fromJson(json)

inline fun <reified T> convertObjectToJson(objectData: T): String =
    moshi.adapter(T::class.java).toJson(objectData)
```

And use it in your converter :

```
class ObjectTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun objectToString(myObj: MyObject): String = convertObjectToJson(myObj)

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToObject(myObjStr: String): MyObject = convertJsonToObject(myObjStr)
}
```

Comment: Can we do it without reflection in Moshi?

Comment: How to make this work for List<SealedClass>?